# Is there a way to check if two lists contain any of the same values in Python?

Tags: python, variables

For example if I had:

```
a = [20,30,56,78,99]
b = [10,20,40,56,99]
```

What could I use so that I could search the 2 lists get the values `20`,`56` and `99`?

**Note:** I can't use the set function on this.

Comment: *"I can't use the set function on this"* Now the obvious question that follows is **Why?**. Use the right tools for the right job.

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? If so, please tag the question with 'homework'. As for the question itself, use a `for` loop to iterate over the first list, use the `in` membership test to see if the current value is in the second list, and if it is, append the value to a third list.

Answer (score 2):

Python sets are a clean, simple way to do it:

```
>>> a = [20,30,56,78,99]
>>> b = [10,20,40,56,99]
>>> set(a) & set(b)
set([56, 99, 20])
```

If you can't use those, the same can be done using dictionaries:

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(b)
>>> for k in a:
        if k in d:
            print k

20
56
99
```

If the elements aren't hashable, just do a straight contains test:

```
>>> for k in a:
        if k in b:
            print k

20
56
99
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use sets for this:

```
a = [20, 30, 56, 78, 99]
b = [10, 20, 40, 56, 99]
print set(a) & set(b)
```

prints

```
set([56, 99, 20])
```

Which is your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
values = [x for x in a if x in b] # note that this allows for duplicates
```

But really, just use sets.